# AWS - Can a KMS replica key be created in a different account from the primary

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

If I created a multi-region CMK in account A, would I be able to create replica keys in another account in a different region, assuming the right permissions are granted? Or must replica keys be created in the same AWS account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly not. Replica keys are account specific. If you want other accounts to access these keys, you have to setup such [permissions through KMS key policies](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/share-kms-account/) in account A.